# TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined - using 'props' in react

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am currently learning React and have hit a problem.

I retrieve a list of JSON information relating to documents which I then pass the `json` as `props` into the following `const`:

```
const Document = props => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(props));
  return(
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-3">{props.dateOnLetter}</div>
      <div className="col-1">{props.personFrom.firstName}</div>
      <div className="col-1">{props.personFrom.lastName}</div>
      <div className="col-1">{props.personTo.firstName}</div>
      <div className="col-1">{props.personTo.lastName}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "dateOnLetter":"2012-04-23T18:25:43.511+0000",
    "personFrom":{
        "id":"5b637d319e30ed3f8c322c64",
        "firstName":"Georgexxx",
        "lastName":"TheCatxxx"
    }
}
```

It complains that the personTo attribute doesnt exist; however the reason I want to include it is that it may exist in some rows.

It complains about the line:

```
<div className="col-1">{props.personTo.firstName}</div>
```

The error is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined - using 'props' in react

So, any idea how I can solve this elegantly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to guard against it not existing. There are a couple of ways to do that. For instance, the conditional operator:

```
<div className="col-1">{props.personTo ? props.personTo.firstName : ""}</div>
<div className="col-1">{props.personTo ? props.personTo.lastName : ""}</div>
```

Live Example:

```js
const Document = props => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(props));
  return(
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-3">{props.dateOnLetter}</div>
      <div className="col-1">{props.personFrom.firstName}</div>
      <div className="col-1">{props.personFrom.lastName}</div>
      <div className="col-1">{props.personTo ? props.personTo.firstName : ""}</div>
      <div className="col-1">{props.personTo ? props.personTo.lastName : ""}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Document dateOnLetter="today" personFrom={{firstName: "Joe", lastName: "Bloggs"}} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Another option is to destructure your `props` on receipt and provide a default for the `personTo` property:

```
const Document = ({dateOnLetter, personFrom, personTo = {firstName: "", lastName: ""}}) => {
  return(
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-3">{dateOnLetter}</div>
      <div className="col-1">{personFrom.firstName}</div>
      <div className="col-1">{personFrom.lastName}</div>
      <div className="col-1">{personTo.firstName}</div>
      <div className="col-1">{personTo.lastName}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Live Example:

```js
const Document = ({dateOnLetter, personFrom, personTo = {firstName: "", lastName: ""}}) => {
  return(
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-3">{dateOnLetter}</div>
      <div className="col-1">{personFrom.firstName}</div>
      <div className="col-1">{personFrom.lastName}</div>
      <div className="col-1">{personTo.firstName}</div>
      <div className="col-1">{personTo.lastName}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Document dateOnLetter="today" personFrom={{firstName: "Joe", lastName: "Bloggs"}} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

You don't have to destructure in the parameter list if you don't want to, and you don't have to destructure everything if you don't want to:

```
const Document = props => {
  const {personTo = {firstName: "", lastName: ""}} = props;
  return(
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-3">{props.dateOnLetter}</div>
      <div className="col-1">{props.personFrom.firstName}</div>
      <div className="col-1">{props.personFrom.lastName}</div>
      <div className="col-1">{personTo.firstName}</div>
      <div className="col-1">{personTo.lastName}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Live Example:

```js
const Document = props => {
  const {personTo = {firstName: "", lastName: ""}} = props;
  return(
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-3">{props.dateOnLetter}</div>
      <div className="col-1">{props.personFrom.firstName}</div>
      <div className="col-1">{props.personFrom.lastName}</div>
      <div className="col-1">{personTo.firstName}</div>
      <div className="col-1">{personTo.lastName}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Document dateOnLetter="today" personFrom={{firstName: "Joe", lastName: "Bloggs"}} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ensure the props.personTo has a default.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks that worked... will accept your answer but have to wait 7 minutes :)

Comment: @ChrisCousins - The above does...?

Comment: Yes. The difference is I prefer that the default is applied before the component is passed the props rather than conditional rendering logic. I prefer that method when I write my tests for components.

Comment: @ChrisCousins - Ah! You mean [default props](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html#declaring-default-props). I thought you meant a default in the destructuring. :-) That would make a good answer (in my view) if you want to post it.

Comment: @ChrisCousins The defaultProps option works as well and is also a very elegant solution: `Document.defaultProps = {
  personTo: {lastName: ""}
};` I'll post it as an aswer and credit you

Answer (score 1):

As [Chris Cousins said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51918945/typeerror-cannot-read-property-firstname-of-undefined-using-props-in-reac#comment90787693_51918969) in a comment, [default props](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html#declaring-default-props) are another option:

```
Document.defaultProps = {
  personTo: {firstName: "", lastName: ""}
};
```